# fedora missing in grub inside ubuntu

Tags: grub2, fedora

I have ubuntu and fedora beside each other and I use both of them but now fedora missing and ubuntu run.
what should I do?It's very important for me

Comment: Try [Grub Customizer](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/11/install-grub-customizer-302-in-ubuntu.html).

Answer (score 1):

Fedora's default install uses LVM. Some with multiple booting suggest not to use the LVM as the advantages of LVM are best when entire drive is LVM.

But Ubuntu does not include LVM driver by default. And mount Fedora partition and then run the update grub.

```
sudo apt-get install lvm2
sudo vgchange -a y
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score -1):

there is a software called easy bcd [easy bcd software for windows](http://www.freewarefiles.com/EasyBCD_program_21892.html)which helps in recovering the grub .u can edit the entries in grub too.
this software belongs to windows but u can use it through wine

Comment: I dont have windows to my system and this is .exe that I dont sure it's work in ubuntu